# Trying to write a function point free, GHCI does not approve

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, pointfree

As an exercise I'm trying to implement interesting parts of the prelude manually. Whenever I spot an opportunity to go point free I take it. However this has led me to a brick wall in the most unlikely place. Using this code:

```
myelem _ [] = False 
myelem x y  = if x == head y then True else myelem x (tail y)
```

I am trying to implement `notElem`. Here are my attempts:

```
-- First
mynotelem = not myelem
```

Understandably blows up due to the types not matching up. This is easily fixed:

```
-- Second
mynotelem x y = not (myelem x y)
```

However the explicit declaration of arguments x and y feels ugly and unnecessary, so I try to get it back into point free style.

```
-- Third
mynotelem = not $ myelem
```

Which fails with

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Bool'
         with actual type `a0 -> [a0] -> Bool'
 In the second argument of `($)', namely `myelem'
 In the expression: not $ myelem
 In an equation for `mynotelem': mynotelem = not $ myelem
```

Fair enough, the types still don't match up. But how do you fix it? Again you can jump straight to

```
-- Fourth
mynotelem x y = not $ myelem x y
```

Which works, but seems dangerously close to just going in circles. I discover it's possible to eliminate one of the arguments:

```
-- Fifth
mynotelem x = not . (myelem x)
```

But that pesky x still remains. How do I eliminate it?

Comment: ThelronKnuckle: If you haven't already, search SO questions for ones regarding the difference between `($)` and `(.)` - I think you will find these questions/answers helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can rewrite your code like this:

```
mynotelem x = not . (myelem x)
            = (not .) (myelem x)
```

Now recognize that this is just `h x = f (g x)` with `f = (not .)` and `g = myelem`, so we can write it point-free with another use of the `(.)` operator as `h = f . g`:

```
mynotelem = (not .) . myelem
```

Note how the pattern continues when composing with functions with more arguments:

```
> let f x y z = x+y+z
> (((sqrt .) .) . f) 1 2 3
2.449489742783178
```

Alternatively, you can also write it with this funny-looking composition of composition operators:

```
mynotelem = ((.).(.)) not myelem
```

For more arguments, the pattern continues like this:

```
> ((.).(.).(.)) sqrt f 1 2 3
2.449489742783178
```

Comment: Shameless plug, I uploaded the "composition" package to hackage to provide convenience functions for the boob operator and friends.

Comment: The boob operator XD Will have to use that as an advantage when pimping haskell to my mates

Comment: Is it at all common to use the "boob operator" in actual code? What's the cleanest way to handle a situation such as this? Would it be better to just leave it with its points (`mynotelem x = not . elem x` or `mynotelem x y = not $ elem x y`)?